# Using classes with angular ngclipboard?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am using a directive called ngclipboard, but it seems to rely on using `id` and nothing else for what content within an element will be copied. I am trying to use it as a class as I have an entire worksheet that has data and I only want certain data copied to the clipboard. A snippet example in particular is using as such:

```
<div class="copyThis">
<div>
  <p class="wsOutputHead">HYPOTHESIS</p>
  <p class="outputText" id="hypCriteria">We believe that <span >{{ solution || '[solution]' }}</span> will solve <span>{{ (problem != null) ? problem : '[problem]' }}</span> and be valuable to  <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span> while doing <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span>.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="copyThis">
          <p class="wsOutputHead">CONCEPT:</p>
<div>
  <p class="outputTextDk">Introduce yourself (and team) and explain the process</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="outputText">"We have been talking to <span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span>'s like you about the different problems they experience while doing <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span>."</li>
    <li class="outputText">"We have a few ideas to share with you that might address <span>{{ (problem != null) ? problem : '[problem]' }}</span> to get your feedback. We want to hear your honest thoughts: will the solutions work or not work for you. We also want to hear your vision of solutions and expectations that might address <span>{{ (problem != null) ? problem : '[problem]' }}</span> when doing <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span>."</li>
    <li class="outputText">"There is no right or wrong, we are talking to you about early ideas of how we might make your job easier when doing <span>{{ (task != null) ? task : '[job to be done]' }}</span> before we start coding a new feature/product."</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I may get this to work with a class rather than just an id for an element so that I may achieve what I am after? Otherwise, is there a better library to facilitate this?

The link is ngclipboard can be seen [here](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/)

Comment: Anyone have anything they can share on this?